# Wrap text when using innerHTML

Tags: javascript, css, angular, innerhtml

In Angular 5 app, I need to show some HTML from database. For instance, the text in database could be

```
<div><u>Documents and Files</u></div><ul><li>These documents needs to be tested and reviewed. Please check the details.</li></ul>
```

In the app, it is shown as

[image: Wrap Text]

Using the following code

```
<div [innerHTML]="description"></div>
```

This works as expected. The only challenge is that text is wrapped in the middle of the word. In the sample posted, 't' and 'he' are in 2 lines.

I would like to wrap text for the whole word rather than break the word for wrapping. In this case 'the' should be in the next line.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I don't think it's relevant that you are using angular, it seems like it's some css which is at play. My guess is that you have a `word-break: break-all` or something similar somewhere.

Comment: Agreeing with @HenrikKarlsson problem is no where related to the framework, but instead of `word-break: break-all` what you are looking for is `word-wrap: break-word;` . This is some really basic css.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a CSS:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

as

```
<li style="white-space: nowrap;">These documents needs to be tested and reviewed. Please check the details.</li>
```

or try to add a css to your component:

```
ul li {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Demo:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5-tutorial-4kghvj?file=app/app.component.css

Comment: Thank you. I am not looking for a nowrap. I want to text to be wrapped but it should get wrapped in a way that words are not broken. In example above, 'the' should be in the next line and not broken at 'he'. So complete word should be wrapped. If I use nowrap then all wrapping disappears and I get a big scrollbar which I don't want.

Comment: I've updated with ``word-wrap: break-word;``, @Naresh Pingale  comment looks good

Comment: Didn't help. I added to the CSS td div {   word-wrap: break-word; } and then in HTML  <td><div [innerHTML]="description"></div></td>

However, it still breaks at the letter.

Comment: I don't know what HTML would come back from the database, so didn't put CSS on ul li. Instead did it on td div (which would always be there). Don't think that should make a difference though

Comment: I have used `word-wrap: break-all;` to fix my same issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
ul li {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Above piece of CSS is all you need for your desired output. Alternative you should also have a look at [overflow-wrap](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/overflow-wrap/) this article very well explains `overflow-wrap` and the difference between both.

Answer (score 0):

```
.yourclass {
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;
    white-space: -pre-wrap;
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Although "word-wrap: break-word" works if the element text caused an overflow (flex grow) it becomes truncated so using the above works in that event

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.